# How to connect UiPath to Qubole Hive cluster and run a query

Tags: hive, rpa, uipath, qubole

One of the teams using RPA in my company wants to automate reporting that is run in Qubole - Hive environment. The initial approach is to unleash the robot to log in to Okta, then Workbench in Qubole, run the query, and download results.

Is there a more straightforward way to do it using UiPath Studio you know about?

Comment: Thanks, Mohit and Pradeep. It turns out that in my org I can only use the rest API option since the data sits on s3. I'll have to explore how to do that using UiPath.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much familiar with the UiPath studio but if UiPath has ODBC/JDBC interface to connect to different data sources, then you can make use of the Qubole ODBC or JDBC driver (refer: [ODBC Driver](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/connectivity-options/use-qubole-drivers/ODBC-driver/index.html)
 and
[JDBC Driver](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/connectivity-options/use-qubole-drivers/JDBC-driver/index.html)
) to directly fire the hive SQL query on Qubole Analyse and the driver will return the results to UiPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilize REST API calls [REST API Reference](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/rest-api/api_overview.html) to submit queries to qubole.